# Выбор даты из MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Имею поле типа datetime, можно ли сделать выборку за конкретный месяц?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да. Можно. В MySQL есть функция [MONTH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)

Будет примерно так:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE MONTH(mydatefield) = 3;
```

Таким образом будут выбраны записи за март. Правда будут выбраны даты за март любого года. Если нужен все конкретный месяц конкретного года, то нужно дополнительно использовать функцию `YEAR`

Comment: Еще вопросик, а нет функции "текущий месяц"? Или можно использовать NOW?

Comment: @oleghalin такой функции нет. Можно использовать `NOW` или `CURDATE`. Но если задача в том чтобы выбрать записи только за текущий месяц, то лучше использовать условие вида `WHERE mydatafield >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')` Мне кажется так будет оптимальней.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `unitpay_payments` WHERE MONTH(dateComplete)=NOW(), по идее такое должно работать, верно?

Comment: @oleghalin Не надо использовать данный метод. он медленный. А ипользование одного только month выберет вам указанный месяц за все года

Comment: @oleghalin нет. `MONTH` возвращает число от 1 до 12, а `NOW` дату.

Comment: Ваш запрос верен только в том случае, если данные имеются только за один год.

Comment: @artoodetoo спасибо за комментарий. Но об этом я написал в своем ответе.

Comment: @newman, признаю — был невнимателен, смотрел только на запрос.

Answer (score 3):

"За конкретный месяц" обычно означает "**за конкретный месяц конкретного года"**. Иначе можно насобирать данные за январь 2016, 2015, 2014 и т.д. Поэтому в выборке должен явно присутствовать год. Этого можно добиться, как минимум, тремя способами:

1. Ограничив дату с обоих сторон, например так:

   … WHERE mydatefield BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-31'
2. Используя функции "месяц" и "год":

   … WHERE YEAR(mydatefield) = 2016 AND MONTH(mydatefield) = 1
3. Используя функию форматирования даты:

   … WHERE DATE_FORMAT(mydatefield, '%Y-%m') = '2016-01'

Насколько я знаю, только первый вариант может использовать индекс, поэтому потенциально он самый быстрый. Остальные гарантируют полный перебор всех записей. Но может быть для вас важнее другие факторы.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: @oleghalin, в комментариях я вижу, что вы интересуетесь как при этом использовать текущую дату. Я рекомендую вычислять её на стороне PHP, а в запрос подставлять уже результат, [отформатированный](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php) к нужному виду.

Answer (score 0):

Конкретный месяц конкретного года?
Лучше пишите полностью условие `fieldname >= '2016-02-01' and fieldname < '2016-03-01'`. Возможно, удобнее будет писать `fieldname >= '2016-02-01' and fieldname < '2016-02-01' + interval '1 month'`. Если надо, данные может подставлять тоже SQL (при этом отвалится `mysql query cache`, правда). Чуть ниже поясню, почему так.

Просто месяц любого года - всё плохо. `MONTH(mydatefield) = 3` можно использовать, но почти наверняка это будет медленно.

Итак, почему же `MONTH(mydatefield) = 3` - это плохо: mysql не умеет функциональные индексы. Следовательно такое условие - это прямой запрет использовать индексы по этому полю. Если у вас есть другой селективный индекс - то хорошо. А если по дате mysql и мог бы эффективно отсечь много лишних данных, то с таким запросом это невозможно.

Если нужно часто искать именно конкретный месяц любого года - придётся эмулировать функциональный индекс. Создаёте отдельное поле числового типа (`tinyint` отлично подойдёт),  куда пишете непосредственно номер месяца. Целостность данных в этом поле можно поддерживать триггерами.

Answer (score 0):

Текущий месяц:

```
select * from table
 where date between date_format(now(),'%Y-%m-01')
            and date_add(last_day(now()),interval "23:59:59" HOUR_SECOND)
```

Для других месяцев заменить `now()` на требуемую дату.

Данный способ, выглядит сложнее, чем использование функции `month()`, но в отличие от него работает гораздо быстрее, т.к. не надо применять функцию к каждой строке и если есть индекс по полю даты - то индекс будет использован.